# Вывод структуру(дерево) категорий

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, laravel

Нужно вывести дерево категорий, в бд таблица выглядит так:

```
|id|parent_id|name  |
|1 |0        |машины|
|2 |0        |лодки |
|3 |1        |bmw   |
```

Нужно вывести дерево такого вида:

```
1
--3
2
```

ПРобовал сделать вот так:

```
$categories_arr = Category::all();
        foreach ($categories_arr as $category) {
            echo $category['id']."<br>";
                $parent_id = Category::where('parent_id', '=', $category['id'])->value('id');
                if ($parent_id !== null) {
                    echo "--".$parent_id."<br>";
                }    
        }
```

Но результат был вот таким

```
1
--3
2
3
--
```

Как сделать так что бы дочернии категории(в данном случае это 3) не выводились дальше в цикле

Comment: Самый простой вариант - создаём массив `$usedCategories = [];`, в него записываем `$parent_id` после его же вывода, а вывод `$category['id']` обернуть в условие `if ( !in_array($category['id'], $usedCategories) ){ echo $category['id']."<br>"; }`

Comment: Версия MySQL - какая? Максимальная вложенность категорий - какая?

Comment: *Как сделать так что бы дочернии категории(в данном случае это 3) не выводились дальше в цикле* Не заниматься фигнёй на стороне PHP, сразу получать элементы в нужном виде в запросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала сделать связь в категории

```
public function childs(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}

public function parent(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(self::class);
}
```

Потом в контроллере делаем выборку

```
public function categories(Request $request, int $category_id = null): View
{
    $categories = Category::with(['childs'])->where('parent_id', $category_id)->get();
    return view('categories', compact('categories'));
}
```

Делаем шаблон для вывода списка категорий **_category_list.blade.php**

```
<ul>
    @foreach($categories AS $category)
    <li>
        {{ $category->name }}
        @if($category->childs()->count())
            @include('_category_list', ['categories' => $category->childs])
        @endif
    </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Либо если вам надо где-то перебрать

```
private function categoryList(Collection $category, $prefix = ''): void
{
    foreach($categories AS $category){
        echo $prefix.$category->id.'<br>';
        if ($category->childs()->count()) {
            $this->categoryList($category->childs, empty($prefix) ? '--' : $prefix.$prefix);
        }
    }
}

public function categories(Request $request, int $category_id = null)
{
    $categories = Category::with(['childs'])->where('parent_id', $category_id)->get();
    $this->categoryList($categories);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно пропускать обработку элементов, у которых поле `parent_id` равняется `null`:

```
$categories_arr = Category::all();
        foreach ($categories_arr as $category) {
            echo $category['id']."<br>";

            if($category['parent_id'] == null){
                continue;
            }

            $parent_id = Category::where('parent_id', '=', $category['id'])->value('id');

            if ($parent_id !== null) {
                echo "--".$parent_id."<br>";
            }    
        }
```